# How to failback with Postgresql cluster using repmgr?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, repmgr

I want to build a Postgresql Cluster in a Cloud environment (yes I know it's a bad idea ... but that is not the question).
For your information, I use a Dockerized Postgresql (see: https://github.com/paunin/postgres-docker-cluster) but that is not the problem and not the question.

So I have installed 2 Postgresql 9.5 with streaming replication.
On each host I have repmgr 3.2.1 installed and correctly configured.

The following case have some issue:

1. stop the master,
2. wait for failover on slave -> ok,
3. restart the old master -> Ko I've got 2 master in the cluster showed by `repmgr cluster show` and I don't find any solution to force the old master to become slave.

The only ugly solution I found is to remove all data of the old master and restart it. Doing this, it became slave as expected (but a full resynchro is needed...).

Please note that It seems to be not possible to force the old master to became slave. `repmgr standby register` don't work as it says:

```
[2016-12-06 15:04:04] [INFO] connecting to standby database
[2016-12-06 15:04:04] [ERROR] this node should be a standby (user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=psg-host21 dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2)
[2016-12-06 15:04:04] [INFO] connecting to database
    Role      | Name       | Upstream   | Connection String
    ----------+------------|------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * master  | psg-host21 |            | user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=psg-host21 dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2
    * master  | psg-host22 | psg-host21 | user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=psg-host22 dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you need high-available Postgres cluster managed by repmgr, you can use the [pg-dock](https://github.com/xcrezd/pg-dock)

This is tool for dockerizing the Postgres cluster with repmgr.